# Failed to load the "Magento_Tax/checkout/shipping_method/price" template

Tags: magento2, checkout, 2.4.6-p2

Showing an error after upgrading the site to Magento 2.4.6-p2

```
Failed to load the "Magento_Tax/checkout/shipping_method/price" template requested by "checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.price".
```

Comment: just try to disable `Magento_QuickCheckout` and `Magento_QuickCheckoutAdminPanel` modules. recently we faced same issue.

Comment: @Pawan I have disabled Magento_QuickCheckout and Magento_QuickCheckoutAdminPanel  from config.php but still, I can see an issue on the checkout page.

Comment: Please rename the tag to `magento2.4.6-p2` for consistency with other tags.